# Load a webpage from another domain and inject javascript

Tags: php, javascript, cross-domain, web, inject

I wish to create a mobile optimized web app by loading a website from a domain( that i do not own) and then running some java script code onto it to modify the layout. How would this be possible as I've read that javascript does not allow cross domain requests.

Would using an iframe and then somehow modify the content of the iframe be possible?

Comment: You have read truth. It is not.

Comment: You could make an app with PhoneGap or something like that.

Comment: How would I go around to doing that? I would still need to load the external website and somehow modify it as I do not have access to the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible without hacks, and barely possible with hacks.